# Cakephp 2.0 login is not working

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I am sorry that I asking this question, I’ve googled the problem and it giving me a lot of  answer but it turns out everything is not working for me. I try to do the login page for one of my website using cakephp 2.0 and what happen is, when I save the user data, the password is not hashing and I can't login using the data that has been saved.

Here are what I have have done so far:

**Model/user.php**

```
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth'); 
class User extends AppModel {
    /* validate data enetered by user */
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A password is required'
            )
        )
    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (!$this->id) {
            $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
            $this->data['User']['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                $this->data['User']['password']
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Controller/AppController.php**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
     public $components = array(
        'Session',
        /* add Auth component and set  the urls that will be loaded after the login and logout actions is performed */
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => array(
                        'className' => 'Simple',
                        'hashType' => 'sha256'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Dashboard', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login')
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        /* set actions that will not require login */
        $this->Auth->allow('index','display', 'view');
    }
}
```

**Controller/UsersController.php**`

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add', 'login'); 

    }

    public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            /* login and redirect to url set in app controller */
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            echo $this->Auth->password('the-chosen-password');
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
         /* logout and redirect to url set in app controller */
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

   public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Users','action' => 'login'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

**View/Users/add.ctp**

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add User'); ?></legend>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

**View/Users/login.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?></legend>
    <?php 
       echo $this->Form->input('username');
       echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
```

I really hope that someone will look over it for me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why would you only hash passwords when the user model's id property exists (or only when you're doing an update essentially). I suggest you should always hash the password if the password exists in the `$data` array passed to `save()`. So change the `beforeSave()` in your User model to the following:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
     if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
         $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
         $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
             $this->data[$this->alias]['password'],
         );
     }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi.. sorry for the delay of my reply.. i've changed the beforeSave() as you told me but its still not changing anything. When I debug the sql shows 

'SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`franchiseeId`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`status` FROM `cuciy`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`username` = 'admin' LIMIT 1'

with effected rows of 1 and Num rows of 1..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but might work...

this `public function beforeFilter() {
        /* set actions that will not require login */
        $this->Auth->allow('index','display', 'view');
    }`

should be in your UsersController. Because you add this to AppController its Allow all index, display and view action as public.

If not work then answer few question...
1. Are you able to register new user and are your password hasher is woring?
2. It there is any error message? If you are using DebugKit, you can easily find the error message.
3. It is looping for infinite?

Comment: Hi Fazal.. thank for the reply.. The only pages i got now is login and add and i've already allowed both of them in beforeFilter.. as for your questions, 1. i am able to register but the password is not hashing.. 2. no error message shown, 3. the looping is fine..

Comment: Try by removing Password hashing setting from Auth Form setting...And your users table password column should be char(64) if you wants to use sha256.

ans few more question: